# Delete a Entire Reg Directory using Perl

Tags: perl, registry, regedit

I would like to Delete the Registry in Windows  Machine using a perl command.
How can I do that . I tried few command from Internet it is getting executed but not deleted
Please provide help !!
The below code executes , but doesn't delete the Reg Key

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Win32::TieRegistry( Delimiter=>"/", ArrayValues=>0 );

my $myway= delete $Registry->{"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Keypath"};

print "Done";
```

Comment: Are you running the perl script with admin privileges? If not, you might not have the rights to delete the key

Comment: @HåkonHægland , How would i able to do that , u mean run from the cmd by opening it as the administrator

Comment: @HåkonHægland I tried the command, it is getting executed but Ultimately, the key is not getting deleted. I think, it is due to admin privilege as you told. But , I tried running the script from the Admin:cmd. Didn't  work.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need the right permission to delete a registry key (try run the Perl script from a CMD with admin privileges), second according to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::TieRegistry#Deleting-items) you can only delete a key provided it does not contain any subkeys:

> You can use the Perl delete function to delete a value from a Registry
> key or to delete a subkey *as long that subkey contains no subkeys* of
> its own.

Third, even if you run with admin privileges there can still be keys that you cannot delete, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63031438/2173773) Q&A for more information.

So if you want to delete an entire subtree, you need to iterate bottom up through the tree and delete each subkey separately. Here is an example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use Win32::RunAsAdmin qw(force);
use Win32API::Registry qw(regLastError KEY_READ KEY_WRITE);
use Win32::TieRegistry( Delimiter=>"/", ArrayValues=>0 );
{
    # Choose the top root node that should be deleted
    # Note: This and all its subkeys will be deleted from the registry.
    # Note: Will only succeed if you have permission to write to each sub key
    my $top_key_name = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Directory/Background/shell/Foo";
    my $tree = $Registry->Open(
        $top_key_name,  
       { Access=>KEY_READ()|KEY_WRITE(), Delimiter=>"/" } 
    );
    die "Could not open key $top_key_name: $^E" if !defined $tree;
    delete_subtree( $tree, my $level = 0);
}

sub delete_subtree {
    my ($tree, $level) = @_;
    my $path = $tree->Path();
    my @subkeys = $tree->SubKeyNames();
    for my $name (@subkeys) {
        my $subtree = $tree->{$name."/"};
        if (!defined $subtree) {
            die "Cannot access subkey $name for $path: " . regLastError() . ". Abort.";
        }
        if (ref $subtree) {
            delete_subtree($subtree, $level + 1);
        }
        else {
            die "Subkey $name for $path is not a hash ref. Abort.";
        }
    }
    
    # assuming the previous recursive code has deleted all sub keys of the 
    # current key, we can now try delete this key
    say "Trying to delete $path ..";
    my $res = delete $Registry->{$path};
    if (!defined $res) {
        die "..Failed to delete key : $^E";
    }
    else {
        say "  -> success";
    }
}
```