# Not able to access some keys in registry using Win32::TieRegistry

Tags: windows, perl, registry

I am on Windows 10 using Strawberry Perl version 5.30 and trying to print out the values of the Registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Directory/Background/shell/WSL` using the Perl module [`Win32::TieRegistry`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::TieRegistry). Here is a screen shot from the Registry Editor app in Windows 10:

[image]

I am using this Perl script to print the value:

```
use feature qw(say);
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

use Win32::TieRegistry( Delimiter=>"/", ArrayValues=>0 );
{
    dump_keys("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Directory/Background/shell/WSL");
    dump_keys("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Directory/Background/shell/AnyCode");
}

sub dump_keys {
    my ($key) = @_;

    say "Dumping keys for $key:";
    my $tree= $Registry->{$key};
    my @keys =  keys %$tree;
    print Dumper(\@keys);
}
```

The output is (running from a CMD terminal with adminstration privileges):

```
>perl p.pl
Dumping keys for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Directory/Background/shell/WSL:
$VAR1 = [];
Dumping keys for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Directory/Background/shell/AnyCode:
$VAR1 = [
          'command/',
          '/'
        ];
```

as seen it prints the `AnyCode` subkey but not the `WSL` subkey. I also checked with running `reg query` from the same CMD:

```
>reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\WSL

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\WSL
    (Default)    REG_SZ    @wsl.exe,-2
    Extended    REG_SZ
    NoWorkingDirectory    REG_SZ
```

So that works fine, but why doesn't the Perl script print the value of the `WSL` subkey?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that even if you run the Perl script as admin, you do not necessarily have write access to a given registry key, see [this](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/take-full-permissions-control-edit-protected-registry-keys/) blog post for more information.

According to the documentation for [Win32::TieRegistry](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::TieRegistry), the default `$Registry` (the tied hash exported by `Win32::TieRegistry`) is opened with both read and write access:

> The virtual root of the Registry pretends it was opened with access
> `KEY_READ()|KEY_WRITE()` so this is the default access when opening keys
> directory via `$Registry`

This explains why some keys cannot be accessed from `$Registry` since it when accessing a key the write permission is required.

As explained in [the blog post](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/take-full-permissions-control-edit-protected-registry-keys/) it is possible to grant yourself write access to any key in the registry by using the `regedit` app in Windows 10.

Another approach is to only require read access (not write access) when opening a tied hash with `Win32::TieRegistry`:

```
use feature qw(say);
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use Win32::RunAsAdmin qw(force);
use Win32API::Registry qw(regLastError KEY_READ);
use Win32::TieRegistry( Delimiter=>"/", ArrayValues=>0 );
{
    my $reg = $Registry->Open("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Directory",
        { Access=>KEY_READ(), Delimiter=>"/" }
    );
    dump_keys($reg, "Background/shell/WSL");
    dump_keys($reg, "Background/shell/AnyCode");
}

sub dump_keys {
    my ($reg, $key) = @_;

    my $tree= $reg->{$key};
    if (!$tree) {
        say "failed: $^E";
    }
    else {
        my @keys =  keys %$tree;
        print Dumper(\@keys);
    }
}
```